# What sagemaker algorithm can be trained by the minimal instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, instance, amazon-sagemaker

I am following [this example](https://github.com/mtm12/SageMakerDemo) on how to train a machine learning model in Amazon-sagemaker. The problem is ml.t2.medium instance fail to satisfy the constraint of K-means algorithm. I can't use the instances that satisfy the constraints of the algorithm(I will ask support for allocation of this resource). My question is there any algorithm from sagemaker that one can train on the MNIST dataset with the minimal instance?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

Noticed when browsing [pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/pricing/) that for training the minimum size is `ml.m5.large` so you will need to look through these to determine which instance type to use.

AWS do provide in their free tier "50 hours of m4.xlarge or m5.xlarge for training".

**Original**

This comes down to a number of factors.

I am not aware of any specific limitations based on algorithms in fact AWS recommend general instance families on [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sagemaker-algo-docker-registry-paths.html), with the k-means algorithm this is targeted at CPU or GPU based instances (so it does not exclusively require GPU).

There are a list of [available instance types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/notebooks-available-instance-types.html) in the documentation that do not mention the instance type you're referring to, I would recommend trying to use the `ml.t3.medium` instance type instead. This is a newer generation and likely to be supported more across current version of the algorithms.

Comment: ml.t3.medium fails to satisfy the constraint as well.

Comment: Do you know which instances are available as part of free tier?

Comment: " monthly free tier of 250 hours of t2.medium or t3.medium notebook usage for building your models, plus 50 hours of m4.xlarge or m5.xlarge for training, plus 125 hours of m4.xlarge or m5.xlarge ". So you can use 50 hours of an m4.xlarge or m5.xlarge per month. https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/pricing/